# Windows PowerShell script help:

Tags: powershell

I need help changing this scrip, instead of coping a certain amount of files I would like it to copy a certain amount of Gb's. Is it Possible? or randomly fill a sd cards free space(like iTunes does until full)

```
#edit this for your settings
$sourceFolder = 'F:\laptop\mp3'
$destFolder = 'F:\random'
$filesToCopy = 4400
$searchFilter = '*.mp3'



function Copy-RandomFiles
{
param (

[Parameter(Mandatory=$true, Position=0)]
[string]$SourceDirectory,

[Parameter(Mandatory=$true, Position=1)]
[string]$DestinationDirectory,

[int]$FilesToCopy = 100,

[string]$SearchFilter = '*.*'
)

$rand = New-Object System.Random

$files = [System.IO.Directory]::GetFiles($SourceDirectory, $SearchFilter, [System.IO.SearchOption]::AllDirectories)

$usedIndexes = @{}
$filteredList = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList

#build list of random indexes
for([int]$i = 0; ($i -lt $FilesToCopy) -and ($i -lt $files.Length); $i++)
{
    $index = $rand.Next(0, $files.Length)
    #loop till we find an available index
    while($usedIndexes.ContainsKey($index))
    {
        $index = $rand.Next(0, $files.Length)
    }

    $usedIndexes.Add($index, $null)
    $dump = $filteredList.Add($files[$index]) #dump is so it does not display a count
}

if($filteredList.Count -gt 0)
{
    Copy-Item -Path $filteredList.ToArray() -Destination $DestinationDirectory
}

$count = $filteredList.Count

Write-Host "$count file(s) copied"
}

Get-ChildItem $destFolder | Remove-Item
Copy-RandomFiles $sourceFolder $destFolder -FilesToCopy $filesToCopy -SearchFilter $searchFilter

Write-Host "Press any key to continue . . ."
$x = $host.UI.RawUI.ReadKey("NoEcho,IncludeKeyDown")
```

Comment: Why not use what you have to select random files and keep copying files until the copy fails because you have run out of space?

Answer (score 1):

The code you provided is unnecessarily complicated, see below:

1. Copy a certain amount of GBs:

```
$sourceFolder = 'F:\laptop\mp3'
$destFolder = 'F:\random'
$searchFilter = '*.mp3'
$limit = 1GB

[long]$bytesCopied = 0
$count = 0
dir $sourceFolder -Filter $searchFilter | % {
   if($bytesCopied + $_.Length -le $limit) {
      Write-Output "Copying $($_.Name)..."
      Copy $_ $destFolder
      $bytesCopied += $_.Length
      $count++
   }
}
Write-Output "`n$count file(s) ($($bytesCopied) bytes) copied."
```

2. Instead of a set limit, if you want to copy until the disk is full, simply change the `$limit` to below:

```
$limit = (gcim Win32_LogicalDisk -Filter "DeviceID='$($destFolder.Substring(0,2))'").FreeSpace
```

Essentially, this changes your size limit to the amount of free space left on your destination drive, so it'll keep copying files until the drive becomes full.

3. If you want to copy a *random* set of files from your source, just modify the "dir" command as below:

```
dir $sourceFolder -Filter $searchFilter | Sort {Random} | % {
```

This will randomly sort your input list of files before passing it on to the loop.